# Strange blank space in the right of my page - CSS

Tags: html, css

From 2 hours I'm looking for what error is on my page because I have a huge blank space...the width is too big and I don't want to have that space. Could you help me to fix my code ?

Here is my website where you can check : https://andrei-my-codepen.000webhostapp.com/

I don't know if it's because of an unclosed tag, or from CSS. But, when I wanted to fix this problem, I saw that, at some divs with class `row`, if I cancel `margin-left: -15px`, that space disappear, maybe is because I have too much `row` class?

[image]

Comment: You set the header to width: 1425px; remove that. That overwrites the width: 100%. You have 2 widths for header remove the width: 1425px;

Comment: @EvikGhazarian thanks but doesn't work :( I edited with `width: 100%` and remove the second width, and same problem.

Comment: add margin: 0px; or margin:0px !important; to your body tag

Comment: Nope, I don't think is a problem with my .body, maybe a little down ? at our-menu or location?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code as using row as a child of class="reservation1" should resolve your problem.

```
  <div class="reservation1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
           <p class="menu-reservation">you want to stand here?</p>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 reservation-div">
      <div class="button-reservation ">
        <p class="reservation-text1 text-center">seat reservation</p>
        <p class="reservation-text2 text-center">Reserve a place in "Good Food" restaurant</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```